# Set custom time precision in tests statistic window in PyCharm IDE

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, ide, pycharm

Basically this question can apply to IntelliJ or any JetBrains IDE.
I run tests in PyCharm 3.1 Community Edition with Nose runner.

In **Run tool window** in **Statistics** subwindow (it can be enabled by turning option Show Statistics in Run window menu see no1 on attached image) 
there is **Time Elapsed** (see no2) table column

[image]

I like to adjust time precision so when I run tests I would like to see time in microseconds instead milliseconds and I believe that tests will be measured with such precision.:)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Nope -- there is no such option unfortunately. But you can file new Feature ticket into their Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 2):

I've got email from JetBrains Support:

> This feature isn't implemented, so I've created feature request with
>   it, please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123672.
>
> Best regards, PyCharm team.

Hopefully some day my question receive different answer :)